# vaadin date format not formatting properly when data loaded with lazyquerycontainer and jpa

Tags: java, jpa, lazy-loading, vaadin, entitymanager

Hi I am using lazyquerycontainer integrated with jpa. As the entity manager loads the data some fields are in bigdecimal format but I want to show in date format. In the filtertable I have defined a decorator also but the format it is displaying is like 20,010,130. 
Is it something I can do in the table itself?
Please help 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you correctly, tables can be overridden to do what you need:

```
        Table t = new Table() {

        @Override
        protected String formatPropertyValue(Object rowId, Object colId,
                Property property) {
            Object v = property.getValue();
            if (v instanceof Date) {
                Date dateValue = (Date) v;
                return "Formatted date: " + (1900 + dateValue.getYear())
                        + "-" + dateValue.getMonth() + "-"
                        + dateValue.getDate();
            }
            return super.formatPropertyValue(rowId, colId, property);
        }

    };
```

example from [vaadin forum](https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/19826/19033)

Comment: I have already overridden this method and I have also given formatting for the table but still I am getting the same result

Comment: Strange, you can always make the condition not on the value but depending on the rowID. In fact you should try to assign a constant first to be sure if it is working or not.
As an additional note, if you are able you should try the grids. They are receiving much more support and these kinds of things are far more easy to achieve.